# Wikidata query: how to get the "proportion" values under "owned by" property?

Tags: sparql, wikidata, wikidata-query-service

I need help with a query on query.wikidata.org.

I'm trying to find a solution how to get the "proportion" (`P1107`) values under "owned by" (P127) property. For example for Audi (`Q23317`), which is owned by the Volkswagen Group, the proportion value should return as `0.9955±0.0001`. Anybody knows how?

I tried this, but nothing returns:

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?owned_by ?owned_byLabel ?proportion 
WHERE {
  wd:Q23317 wdt:P127 ?owned_by.
  ?statement wikibase:claim ?p.
  ?statement wikibase:statementProperty ?ps.
  ?statement wikibase:qualifier ?pq.
  ?pq ps:P6782 wd:Q21503247.
  ?statement ps:P127 ?owned_by.
  ?statement ps:P1107 ?proportion.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the correct query:

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?owned_by ?owned_byLabel ?proportion 
WHERE {
  ?item p:P127 ?statement.
  ?statement ps:P127 ?owned_by.
  ?statement pq:P1107 ?proportion.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
```

[Here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/SPARQL/WIKIDATA_Qualifiers,_References_and_Ranks#Qualifiers) you can find a valid resource on how to query for Wikidata qualifiers.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, since I asked I also realised that with this line works too: 
OPTIONAL { ?item  p:P127 [ps:P127 ?owned_by; pq:P1107 ?proportion] }